# GKE Ingress doesn't get static IP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gke-networking

Ingress doesn't get a static ip. The static ip is global.

Ingress manifest:

```
    ~/temp  cat stage-api-deleted-com-cert.yaml                                                                                                                                ✔
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: devstaticip
  name: stage-api-deleted-com-cert
  namespace: default
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: deleted-gateway-service-https
      port:
        number: 8989
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev-api.deleted.com
    secretName: dev-api-deleted-com-cert
```

kubectl describe ingress/

```
    ~/temp  kubectl describe ingress/stage-api-deleted-com-cert
Name:             stage-api-deleted-com-cert
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  deleted-gateway-service-https:8989 (<none>)
TLS:
  dev-api-deleted-com-cert terminates dev-api.deleted.com
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           *     deleted-gateway-service-https:8989 (<none>)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: true
              kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: devstaticip
Events:
  Type     Reason  Age                  From                     Message
  ----     ------  ----                 ----                     -------
  Normal   Sync    72s                  loadbalancer-controller  UrlMap "k8s2-um-g4e2azkm-default-stage-api-deleted-com-cert-xkz9puyb" created
  Normal   Sync    69s                  loadbalancer-controller  TargetProxy "k8s2-tp-g4e2azkm-default-stage-api-deleted-com-cert-xkz9puyb" created
  Normal   Sync    57s (x3 over 2m22s)  loadbalancer-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal   Sync    52s                  loadbalancer-controller  ForwardingRule "k8s2-fr-g4e2azkm-default-stage-api-deleted-com-cert-xkz9puyb" created
  Warning  Sync    2s (x10 over 50s)    loadbalancer-controller  Error syncing to GCP: error running load balancer syncing routine: loadbalancer g4e2azkm-default-stage-api-deleted-com-cert-xkz9puyb does not exist: googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/smarter-ai-service/global/sslCertificates/k8s2-cr-g4e2azkm-wr44xnxqvebjy33n-e3b0c44298fc1c14' was not found, notFound
```

I tried to recreate an IP address several times. Also, I tried to use ingress.regional-static-ip-name instead of ingress.global-static-ip-name. The same result occurred without the TLS option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not absolutely sure, but it looks like the `networking.gke.io/static-ip: "devstaticip"` annotation helps to get a static ip in my case.

Comment: Yeah you need the quotes